# TNS protocol adapter error Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, service, oracle12c

I'm using Oracle 12c on Win10. When launching SQL Plus and trying to login (I'm using a virtual account), an error shows up:

```
ORA-12560: TNS protocol adapter error
```

I've checked the services, and none of Oracle services are even on the list. Is there any way I could install/activate them?

Comment: There are various things that can cause this. Maybe include the `lsnrctl status` output in the question, and the DB's `local_listener` parameter value, whether your hosts file include an entry for `localhost` (depending on the previous two) or whether nay host names referenced by either resolve properly.

Comment: Please tell me how I can get this status?

Comment: Run `lsnrctl status` on the server. I would have thought you would have used that (or maybe just `lsnrctl services`) when you 'checked the services'. For the local listener you'd need to get into the DB from the server (local/bequeath connection), but you may need to do that to fix the issue.

Comment: I meant Windows service that I accessed through my Services menu (services.msc). Nothing containing Oracle in its name.

Comment: Then Oracle isn't running and you need to start it? Assuming it's supposed to be running on your PC vs. trying to access a remote DB, or one in a VM running on your PC (not sure what you mean by 'virtual account'?). Just having SQL\*Plus available doesn't tell us much - could be a client-only installation, or even instant client.